# Inserting data into table with year dates and time in four column with dbms(range of time)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Hi dear I have a table with columns DT, DT2, DT3, DT4 I can insert in one column but not at all column same time please if you have any idea then told me thanks in advance my code is

```
insert into calendar_dateS4 (DT,DT2,DT3, DT4, DT5 )
SELECT DT, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5
        
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1) )
                  +  INTERVAL '08:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
         
                  +  INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
         
                  +  INTERVAL '05:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
         
                  +  INTERVAL '13:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         
                  +  INTERVAL '21:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                         
                        
                  AS DT, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1) )
                  < ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 12 )
       )
```

Comment: This select returns a single column: DT, created as SUM of certain intervals. What would be other columns' values?

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` is failing because your `SELECT` statement is not valid. Work on getting a valid `SELECT` statement with the results you want, then convert that into an `INSERT` statement.

To insert the same time into all 5 columns, you can use a statement like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO calendar_dateS4 (DT,
                             DT2,
                             DT3,
                             DT4,
                             DT5)
    SELECT dt,
           dt,
           dt,
           dt,
           dt
      FROM (    SELECT   DATE '2020-01-01'
                       + FLOOR ((LEVEL - 1))
                       + INTERVAL '08:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + INTERVAL '16:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + INTERVAL '05:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + INTERVAL '13:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + INTERVAL '21:45' HOUR TO MINUTE
                       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () * INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE    AS DT
                  FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR ((LEVEL - 1)) < ADD_MONTHS (DATE '2020-01-01', 12))
```

Comment: its just inserting only in one dt no in all others dt2 to dt5 are empty

Comment: its just inserting only in one dt no in all others dt2 to dt5 are empty

Comment: If you want random values for D2 through D5 just copy the logic for the DT column into the other 4 columns.

Comment: I want same time insert into all column as just DT in this column so why write all that query

Comment: Just updated the query based on your comment.

Comment: it updated same all column as dt all column same result

Comment: Is that not what you were trying to do? Your question is very vague and unclear.

Comment: dear question and all parameter already shown in code what i want i want to insert all data as you made but in every line see time is changed. by your answer data inserted but same in every column i want all column change as after `Interval`

Comment: as in first column I am inserting time from random in dt`08:45` in second dt2 i am inserting `16:45` and so on

Comment: @MTO or **Littlefoot** Please if you see this you can do this